# Почему нельзя обратиться к компонентам input?

Tags: ajax, html, php

Добрый вечер, друзья! Я тут решаю проблемы с динамической подрузкой данных на страницу без обновления (Через ajax).

По поводу кода. В файле Select.php в php сделал формирование таблицы Товары (данные берустся из базы mysql):

```
    <caption>
        Товары
        </caption>
        <tr>
          <th >Номер товара</th>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>Редактирование</th>
        </tr> 
<?php
    include('config.php');

    // достаем из базы данных ID и заголовок всех статей
    $result = $connect->query("select article_id, article_title from article ORDER BY article_title");
    //определяем количество полученных записей
    $colResult = $result->num_rows;

    if($colResult > 0)
    {
       for($i = 0; $i < $colResult; $i++)
       {
          $row = $result->fetch_object();
          echo"<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row->article_id."</td>";
          echo "<td><span name='text_title[".$row->article_id."]'>".$row->article_title."</span>
          <input type='text' name='edit_title[".$row->article_id."]' value='".$row->article_title."' style='display:none'></td>";
          echo "<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='check_button' value='".$row->article_id."'></center></td>";
          echo "</tr>"; 
        }
    }   
?>
```

А на главной странице index.html идет скрипт такой:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Сайтик</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( 
    function() 
    {

     //функция динамического вывода данных в таблице
     function Createtable()
     {
        $.ajax(
               {type: 'POST', 
                url: 'select.php', 
                success: function(response)
                 {
                   $('#html-data-table').html(response);
                 }
                } 
               );
     }

     // Нажимаем любой из флажков
     $('input[name=check_button]').change( 
     function () 
     { 
        alert('Мы нажали на один из ческбоксов'); 
     });

 }
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
...
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="html-data-table">

</table>
<input type="button" name="editArticle" value="Изменить выделенные товары">
<input type="button" name="deleteArticle" value="Удалить выделенные товары"><br>
</div>
```

Вопрос такой, как заставить срабатывать alert в блоке функции  $('input[name=check_button]').change(? С учетом того что эти самые check_button были сформированы в другом файле (select.php) и переданы Ajax запросом в index.html в тег `<table>`.

Comment: за что минусуют меня? У меня же вопрос нормальный вроде. Тем более я новичок в ajax и js. Не пойму почему при передаче данных через Ajax на главную страницу по коду все равно данных нет там.

Comment: При просмотре кода страницы отображается первичный ЗАГРУЖЕННЫЙ вариант, без обновлений ajax. С обновлениями можно посмотреть в консоли shift+ctrl+i

Comment: Ну тогда вопрос такой почему у меня перестала работать функция обрабатывающая нажатие флажков. Просто ставлю:

     $('input[name=check_button]').change( 
       function () 
       { 
         alert('Мы нажали на один из ческбоксов'); 
     }); 

Когда до вынесения кода по формированию таблицы с данными (в том числе и с checkbox'ами) все работало и в эту функцию входило?

Comment: Насколько я понял у вас подгружаются ajax'ом новые input? 

А функция обработчик, по ходу, привязана к старым... наверное, так.

Comment: ВСЕГДА ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ функцию jquery on()

тогда обработчики будут привязываться и к новым элементам!

    $('input[name=check_button]').on('change',function(){});

Comment: Да ajax'ом подргружается вся таблица, в том числе и input'ы. Надо попробовать твой способ, Deus.

Comment: Другого способа нет, мой друг )))

Comment: Что вообще перестает работать js когда вставляю этот кусок кода...: 

    $('input[name=check_button]').on('change',function(){ 
     alert('Нажат один из ческбоксов');
    }); 
Может кто даст еще советы, как победить это зло? Обращаться к внедренным из ajax запроса компонентам не могу.

Comment: победить очень просто. надо почитать документацию. у вас jquery версии 1.6. в ней нет `on`, зато есть `live`, `bind` и `delegate`. читайте, пробуйте, в документации есть также примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('change','input[name=check_button]',function(){});

$("input[name=check_button]").live("change", function(){});
```

Comment: К сожалению, друг, не работает и эта конструкция, не выводит alert. Не знаю даже что делать-то(. Такое ощущение как-будто флажков с именем check_button нет вовсе, хотя они сформированны в файле select.php и присланы на главный файл index.html в виде ajax-запроса.

Comment: Какая версия jQuery?

У меня работает

Comment: Вы консоль умеете открывать? Там описываются все ошибки javascript. Ошибка может быть и ранее, поэтому скрипт может и не доходить до вашего on()

Comment: http://jquery-docs.ru/events/live/

там про live()

Comment: Тут же в коде написано выше, что я внешнюю библиотеку подключаю. src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" соотвественно 1.6.4. Пользуюсь браузером opera, там в инструментариях не нашел вроде отладки и консоли. Скажите, как открывать ее.

Comment: @IntegralAL - смотрите комментарий выше - там про live() - это то, что вам поможет!
Ваш jquery не подерживает on()!
опера тоже - shift+ctrl+i

Comment: Все заработало с live! Спасибо тебе Deus, за твое столь терпеливое участие к моей проблеме). Не знаю уж кто тут меня минусует, даже совета спросить нельзя.